# 'Render': 'class' type redefinition (C2011)

Tags: c++, visual-studio

There are a lot of similar questions on Stack Overflow, regarding this topic.

I am creating a project with multiple files (.cpp and .h). I am getting the error:

> C2011: 'Render': 'class' type redefinition

I have read about it. Some people are saying use guards, so I am using `#pragma once` on all header files. Some people say the header is being included multiple times, but the guards will prevent that. So what am I doing wrong?

Code:

**Cubes.h**

```
#pragma once

char orientation(int sides, int hV);

std::vector<char> visOrd(std::string *xOrd, int *pov, int ord);

std::vector<int> convertColour(std::vector<std::string> rlBoxCol);

std::tuple<std::vector<int>, std::vector<std::string>> organiseLayers(std::vector<int> boxCoords, std::vector<std::string> rlBoxCol, std::vector<float> rot);


class Render
{
private:
    std::vector<float> rot;
    std::vector<int> boxCoords;
    std::vector<std::string> rlBoxCol;
    int gridSize;
    int cubeSize;
    std::vector<int> offset;

public:
    Render();


    void setRotation(std::vector<float> setRot);
    std::vector<float> getRotation();

    void setCoordinates(std::vector<int> setBoxCoords);
    std::vector<int> getCoordinates();

    void setColours(std::vector<std::string> setRlBoxCol);
    std::vector<std::string> getColours();

    void setSizeOfGrid(int setGridSize);
    int getSizeOfGrid();

    void setSizeOfCubes(int setCubeSize);
    int getSizeOfCubes();

    void setOffset(std::vector<int> setOffset);
    std::vector<int> getOffset();


    void display();
};
```

**Cubes.cpp**

```
#include "Cubes.h"
#include "Global.h"

char orientation(int sides, int hV)
{
// Code
}

std::vector<char> visOrd(std::string *xOrd, int *pov, int ord)
{
// Code
}


std::vector<int> convertColour(std::vector<std::string> rlBoxCol)
{
// Code
}

std::tuple<std::vector<int>, std::vector<std::string>> organiseLayers(std::vector<int> boxCoords, std::vector<std::string> rlBoxCol, std::vector<float> rot)
{
// Code
}



Render::Render()
{
    this->rot;
    this->boxCoords;
    this->rlBoxCol;
    this->gridSize;
    this->cubeSize;
    this->offset;
}


void Render::setRotation(std::vector<float> setRot)
{ // Set rotation
    rot = setRot;
}
std::vector<float> Render::getRotation()
{ // Get rotation
    return rot;
}

void Render::setCoordinates(std::vector<int> setBoxCoords)
{
    boxCoords = setBoxCoords;
}
std::vector<int> Render::getCoordinates()
{
    return boxCoords;
}

void Render::setColours(std::vector<std::string> setRlBoxCol)
{
    rlBoxCol = setRlBoxCol;
}
std::vector<std::string> Render::getColours()
{
    return rlBoxCol;
}

void Render::setSizeOfGrid(int setGridSize)
{
    gridSize = setGridSize;
}
int Render::getSizeOfGrid()
{
    return gridSize;
}

void Render::setSizeOfCubes(int setCubeSize)
{
    cubeSize = setCubeSize;
}
int Render::getSizeOfCubes()
{
    return cubeSize;
}

void Render::setOffset(std::vector<int> setOffset)
{
    offset = setOffset;
}
std::vector<int> Render::getOffset()
{
    return offset;
}


void Render::display()
{
// Drawing code
}
```

**EDIT:**

I have now changed the code in ways you said. Now I am getting errors LNK2005 and LNK1169. What's gone wrong now?

**EDIT 2:   (Errors)**

> LNK2005
>
> "class sf::RenderWindow Window" (?Window@@3VRenderWindow@sf@@A) already defined in Cubes.obj
>
> C:\Users\George\Documents\C++\Projects\Don't fall\Don't fall\main.obj 1

.

> LNK2005
>
> "class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > status" (?status@@3V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@A) already defined in Cubes.obj
>
> C:\Users\George\Documents\C++\Projects\Don't fall\Don't fall\main.obj 1

.

> LNK1169
>
> one or more multiply defined symbols found
>
> C:\Users\George\Documents\C++\Projects\Don't fall\Debug\Don't fall.exe    1

**Global.h:**

```
#pragma once
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>

// This is where all my global variables will be


extern sf::RenderWindow Window(sf::VideoMode(500, 500), "Maximize window to play the game");
extern std::string status = "NULL";
```

Comment: You need to include the header, omit the redefinition of the class and properly preface the methods with Render:: (see answer below).

Comment: You are missing a } at the end of Render::Render()

Answer (score 1):

Your Cubes.cpp does redefine the class Render.  In general the .h file has the class prototype and the .cpp defines the methods.

Try adding this to the top of the Cubes.cpp:

```
#include "Cubes.h"
```

removing this from the top of Cubes.cpp:

```
class Render
{
private:
    std::vector<float> rot;
    std::vector<int> boxCoords;
    std::vector<std::string> rlBoxCol;
    int gridSize;
    int cubeSize;
    std::vector<int> offset;

public:
```

and removing this from the bottom:

```
};
```

Comment: Thanks for that reply, but it hasn't solved my problem. However, I updated the code as you suggested and on other questions. Please look at the new code, and the error I am getting. I still can't find a solution

Answer (score 0):

This is not how you provide the implementation of a class in C++. The keyword `class` defines the class, which is what you have in your header (`.h` file). In the `.cpp` file you wish to implement the methods which you defined in your header file, so you should not redefine the entire class. Rather, you need to provide implementations for the methods (member functions) of the class, like so:

```
void Render::setRotation(std::vector<float> setRot)
{ // Set rotation
    rot = setRot;
}

std::vector<float> Render::getRotation()
{ // Get rotation
    return rot;
}
```

Notice the prefix `Render::`? This is how you indicate that you are providing an implementation for the function `setRotation` of the class `Render`. Just add the function implementation like this in your cpp, do not nest them within a `class`, do not include any fields (the member fields have already been defined in the header, they are done).

**Update**:

OK, so according to the updated answer your linker error refers to the instances `sf::RenderWindow Window` and `std::string status`; this error occurs when linking `main.obj` (from `main.cpp`?) with `Cubes.obj`. The error is telling you that both `main.obj` and `Cubes.obj` define these variables.

I recommend that you read about "Compilation Units" in C++ and difference between *declaration* and *definition* of a symbol; but to give a *very* brief summary:

Essentially, the compiler runs on a single "compilation unit"; you can think of it as a single file. What the `#include`-statement does is basically copy/paste the content of the included file into the compilation unit. So when you compile `Cubes.cpp`, it will go through all of the nested includes until it has generated one huge `cpp`-file with everything included. Then it will build this into an `.obj` file. Then you do the same thing with `main.cpp`, and any other `.cpp` files you might have. Finally, the linker will attempt to link these object files together to produce the final result.

Now, if the linker finds duplicate *definitions* when linking two objects you will get an error. So you cannot have two global variables with the same name! If both `Cubes.cpp` and `main.cpp` include `global.h`, then both compilation units contain global variable definitions `Window` and `status`. This is causing your linker error.

This is why you put a *declaration* in the header (since it is included in multiple compilation units), and the *definition* in the source file (typically not included elsewhere). You build the source file to produce the only object file containing the *definition*; all other object files only reference the *declaration*. The linker can then link those references to the *definition* found in one the object files.

So you want to *declare* the variables in the header, and move the *definition* somewhere else. For instance, to `main.cpp`; but that depends entirely on the rest of your application and what you are trying to achieve. Outside the scope of the question.

Comment: I have just tried that, and I am getting errors pointing towards main.obj. The variables in the error are from a file, "Global.h" (and Global.cpp), so I think my global variables are messing up.

Comment: That is different problem then, can you please edit your question with the required details?

Comment: The variables that were from the class, are in the same colour as my global variables. So is that causing the problem? Do I need some constructor to prevent this?

Comment: Best if you post the actual error and what you have in those global files.

Comment: It's too complicated to put in a question - I'll do research on this problem, and post if I get nothing

Comment: @George_E Can you please add the complete error message to your question? Just the error code is not enough information.

Comment: Added error message :) Thanks for being determined to help